# Нужна ли запятая

Tags: пунктуация

Я внимательно читаю газету и мне нравится, что в ней мы знакомимся с участниками Великой Отечественной войны. Надо ли ставить запятую перед "и"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Надо ли** ставить запятую перед "и"?

НАДО -- для разделения частей сложносочинённого предложения.